# Is there anyway to include WebView or any other same object into c++ project?

Tags: c++, qml, qt-creator, sailfish-os

I've got a problem with including QWebView into .cpp file while creating Sailfish app. Later I figured out QWebView is not supported anymore and now there's WebEngine only. But I can't also find how to include WebEngine.

Also, if you can help me: I can't display a web page using simple qml. If you have a wish to check and help - I'll publish a code.

Comment: use webview https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html

Comment: Thanks for ur reply!
But QML says that module not found